# How to fix "AttributeError: 'JpegImageFile' object has no attribute 'read'?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I am a beginner and I am learning to code an image classifier. My goal is to create a predict function.

Any suggestion to fix it?

In this project, I want to use the predict function to recognize different flower species. So I could check their labels later.

Attempt to fix: Unfortunately, the error is still persistent. I have already tried these codes:

```py
img = process_image(Image.open(image))
img = torch.from_numpy(img).type(torch.FloatTensor)
```

This is the error that I need to fix now.

> AttributeError: 'JpegImageFile' object has no attribute 'read'

**Code:**

```py
# Imports here
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import torch
from torch import nn
from torchvision import datasets, transforms, models
import torchvision.models as models
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torchvision.transforms.functional as F
from torch import optim
import json

from collections import OrderedDict
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
from PIL import Image

def predict(image, model, topk=5):

#Predict the class (or classes) of an image using a trained deep #learning model.
#Here, image is the path to an image file, but input to process_image #should be Image.open(image).                                                         

    img = process_image(Image.open(image))
    img = torch.from_numpy(img).type(torch.FloatTensor) 

    output = model.forward(img)
    probs, labels = torch.topk(output, topk)        
    probs = probs.exp()

    # Reverse the dict
    idx_to_class = {val: key for key, val in
model.class_to_idx.items()}
    # Get the correct indices
    top_classes = [idx_to_class[each] for each in classes]

    return labels, probs
```

```py
predict(image,model)
print(probs)
print(classes)
```

**Error:**

```py
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-b49fdcab5791> in <module>()
----> 1 probs, classes = predict(image, model)
      2 print(probs)
      3 print(classes)

<ipython-input-31-6f996290ea63> in predict(image, model, topk)
      5       Image.open(image)
      6     '''
----> 7     img = process_image(Image.open(image))
      8     img = torch.from_numpy(img).type(torch.FloatTensor)
      9 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py in open(fp, mode)
   2587         exclusive_fp = True
   2588 
-> 2589     prefix = fp.read(16)
   2590 
   2591     preinit()

AttributeError: 'JpegImageFile' object has no attribute 'read'
```

All I want is to get these similar result. Thank you!

```py
tensor([[ 0.5607,  0.3446,  0.0552,  0.0227,  0.0054]], device='cuda:0')   
tensor([[  8,   1,  31,  24,   7]], device='cuda:0')
```

Comment: Hi @Paula could you show me where is `process_image()`function definition?

Answer (score 4):

Converting image to RGB after openning solved the issue for me

```
   PIL.Image.open(image_path).convert('RGB')
```

Answer (score 1):

What is `image`? Where does it come from?

It looks like it's something that's already been `Image.open()`ed, and you're attempting to re-read it, as if it were a file or a path.

Comment: You asked an interesting question. image is an image_path.

Comment: It certainly doesn't look like it, based on the exception you're getting.

Comment: Maybe, should I change the name of the pathway?

Comment: This answer helped me to realize I was insisting on an already opened image. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use function `numpy.asarray(image)` to convert JpegImageFile into numpy array and then you will be able to work with image.

Comment: this doesn't seem to help

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when Trying to open an image that had already had Image.open() called on it. the following will work for you:

```
img = process_image(image)
img = torch.from_numpy(img).type(torch.FloatTensor)
```

if you the type of the image and/or the image you will see it is already a tensor:

```
print(image
print(type(image))
```

here is a related link that is answering the same questions:

https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/typeerror-img-should-be-pil-image-got-class-str/49644

Comment: I tried this and got:
```
<ipython-input-66-5cbbf7021c68> in <module>()
      2 
      3 image_path = './flowers/test/1/image_06743.jpg'
----> 4 predict(image_path, model, topk=5)

<ipython-input-65-557492144ffb> in predict(image_path, model, topk)
     11     # Open
     12     img = process_image(image_path)
---> 13     img = torch.from_numpy(img).type(torch.FloatTensor)
     14 
     15     # Pre-process the image

TypeError: expected np.ndarray (got tuple)```

Any idea why it expected an array and how to convert it into an array?

Comment: It appears as if you are actually passing an image path (i.e. a string) to your predict function for which reason it is giving you that error. Since that is the case the OP's original line of code should work for you: ``img = process_image(Image.open(image))
img = torch.from_numpy(img).type(torch.FloatTensor)`` It did not work for him because his image input parameter was already an Image.open(image_path) object, since yours is an image path it should open the image and convert it into an array which will then be converted into a tensor @rachelvsamuel

Comment: Note: Note img = process_image(Image.open(image)) <- converts image to np array img = torch.from_numpy(img).type(torch.FloatTensor) <- converts np array to a pytorch tensor. @rachelsamuel

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar issue and solved it by opening the image as follows:

```py
import io
from PIL import Image as pil_image

fname = 'my_image.jpg'

with open(fname, 'rb') as f:
    img = pil_image.open(io.BytesIO(f.read()))
    pass
```

rather than:

```py
from PIL import Image as pil_image

fname = 'my_image.jpg'

with pil_image.open(fname, 'r') as img:
    pass
```